# How to choose the "right" font size for a given page

Tags: typography, typefaces, font-size, paper-size

I asked a similar [question in TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126566/412) and I am not 100% happy with the answers. I find it strange that there's no standard formula that yields the "right" font size given the page's size. Therefore, I'm going one level above --- leaving the practical TeX world --- and try to find a general answer. I know that it is desired to have 65 +/- 15 characters per line. Is the only way to achieve this is to iteratively improve the document?

I hope that my question makes sense...

Comment: There is no standard formula, if there were youd have much more luck on TeX.SE than GD.SE. Wellcome anyway. This isnt mathematics.

Comment: Fonts are different, that's why there is no exact rule.

Comment: Why would you need iterations to achieve approximately 65 characters per line? The average width of a character for a given font and fontsize is known, so you just need to set your text area to 65 times that width.

Comment: Answers at Tex.se seem valid to me. Especially the one marked correct. Cross-posting will likely not result in better answers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of variables including the context in which the text is being used and with the message that one wants to communicate which also ties into which typeface/font is selected. Generally most body text falls between 10 to 14 pt. Ultimately though there is no "perfect" font size for a given page - as Robert Bringhurst notes in his seminal book, "The Elements of Typographic Style", "Principle 1.1.1: Typography exists to honor the content." Therefore the font choice, size, leading, and lineheight choices should be based on the content and the desired impression/message you wish to communicate.